# Datepicker validation 18 years of age

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a date picker from twitter bootstrap and I want to add some validation that your sign up will not suppose to be registered once your date is below 18 years of age, how am I supposed to do that? here is my sample html code for the birthdate:

```
<label>Date of Birth*</label>
<input type="date" name="birth_date" tabindex="7" style="height: 30px;" required>
```

Comment: Set the `min` attribute based on today's date - 18 years (html5). But, anyway, you have to check it on server-side and/or with js.

Comment: Best way is to proceed to javascript limitation for user experience and php limitation for security.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont know how to do it in javascript, I'm just a beginner in developing.. so sorry, will someone show me how to do it?

Comment: You either need to (a) brush up on your basic Javascript skills and work your way up to something a bit more complex such as this, or (b) hire a professional to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look down the demo page a bit, you'll see a "Restricting Datepicker" section. Use the dropdown to specify the "Year dropdown shows last 20 years" demo , and hit view source:

```
$("#restricting").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: "-20:+0", // this is the option you're looking for
    showOn: "both", 
    buttonImage: "templates/images/calendar.gif", 
    buttonImageOnly: true 
});
```

You'll want to do the same (obviously changing -20 to -100 or something).

Or you can use

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    startDate: '-15d',
    endDate: '+0d' // there's no convenient "right now" notation yet
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the user input either using javascript or the scripting language you're going to use.

An example in PHP would be:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['birth_date']))
{
   if($_POST['birth_date'] < 1996)
   {
      echo 'You can not register';
   }

}
```